# How to convert Iterable[String, String, String] to DataFrame?

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset of `(String, String, String)` which is about 6GB. After parsing the dataset I did `groupby` using `(element => element._2)` and got `RDD[(String, Iterable[String, String, String])]`. Then `foreach` element in `groupby` I am doing `toList` in-order to convert it to `DataFrame`.

```
val dataFrame = groupbyElement._2.toList.toDF()
```

But It is taking a huge amount of time to save data as parquet file format.
Is there any efficient way I can use?
N.B. I have five node cluster. Each node has 28 GB RAM and 4 cores. I am using standalone mode and giving 16 GB RAM to each executor.

Comment: Why do you use RDD API at all? Why don't you deal with the dataset using Dataset API from the very beginning?

Comment: Actually, I got an RDD of (String, String, String) after parsing the dataset.

Comment: A dataset (all letters lowercase) != a Dataset (`D` is uppercase). You've got a `RDD[(String, String, String)]` after parsing the dataset, but I'm asking why you don't parse the dataset using the Dataset API in Spark SQL? Why do you use Spark Core's RDD API at all?!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am going to try using dataset.

Comment: @AbirChokraborty If you want to use dataframes/datasets instead of RDD, I believe my answer will help you as it is based on those ideas. It should give you a performance boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the dataframe/dataset methods instead of those for RDD. It can look something like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("ABC", "123", "a"),
  ("ABC", "321", "b"),
  ("BCA", "123", "c")).toDF("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
scala> df.show
+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|
+----+----+----+
| ABC| 123|   a|
| ABC| 321|   b|
| BCA| 123|   c|
+----+----+----+

val df2 = df
  .groupBy($"Col2")
  .agg(
    collect_list($"Col1") as "Col1_list"), 
    collect_list($"Col3") as "Col3_list"))
scala> df2.show
+----+----------+---------+
|Col2| Col1_list|Col3_list|
+----+----------+---------+
| 123|[ABC, BCA]|   [a, c]|
| 321|     [ABC]|      [b]|
+----+----------+---------+
```

Additionally, instead of reading the data into a RDD you could make use of the methods to get a dataframe directly.